# Secure Coding with getchar() and Whitespace Padding

Tags: c, getchar, secure-coding

This chunk of code is part of a larger project. I tell you this because it is relevant. I'm working on a small (codewise) database to keep track of all my photos. I'm designing it so that I can later extend the program to store the citations in all my papers.

For better or for worse, I've settled on a simple flat file system with fixed width fields. That may not be the most efficient use of memory, and the files sizes get fluffed up, but it has some super advantages: No delimiters so the files easily remain human readable with nice formatting, and easy array access using simple array indexing.

I like the last part particularly because it lays within my skills.
One thing about this database is that I need to be able to make a lot of entries FAAAA…ST! The bottleneck emerges in the user input part, not memory, and not disk space, so I'm concentrating on making the input wicked fast and easy.

I've learned that getting user input in C can be a tricky thing. C's string handling library has a lot of functions that can be exploited to generate buffer overflow. So… For this code, I implemented some advice from Robert C. Seacord's *Secure Coding in C and C++* Specifically the chapter, "Strings and Buffer Overflows."

Here's a link: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036582&seqNum=5

Seacord suggests that using fgets() to process input lines, while possible to do securely, has performance limitations. (I like fast. Don't you?) He further suggests using getchar() instead. That's what I did.

Here's his suggestion for the use of a while loop for using getchar() securely:

```
while(( (ch = getchar()) != \n) && ch != EOF)
```

In my code below, I tweak that a touch.

There are several things I need the I/O to do. First, if the input entered is too long, I WANT it to truncate. Even though I'm maybe the only user, I might make a mistake. Second, if the input is shorter than the field width—which is *mainly* the case—I want to pad that field with spaces to the right.

That's the problem I'm having. More on that in a bit.

This whitespace keeps the flatfile clean looking, and, again, makes indexing extremely easy. I need to just hit the "Enter" key and move on to the next entry, sequentially, knowing the computer has formatted the data just the way I want it.

(This is actually a crude implementation E.F. Codd's principle that the data must be shielded from direct access. Everything must be checked, polished, parsed, etc., before it gets into storage. This prevents data corruption.)

In this code, I've cut all that last out because it's just noise, and I get pretty sick of trying to read other people's code who post their whole damn program with all sorts of extraneous stuff instead of just the part that's giving them trouble. At the same time, I like to post a *complete* program that can just be selected, copied, pasted, saved, and compiled. So I've done that here. I've left in the comments and my little checks which I'll uncomment to make sure everything is as it should be, then comment out again, so this is not the simplest possible code, but what's that famous Einstein quote about *too* simple?

Anyhow, I know all that is a bit long, but I wanted to sketch out the design principles I was using. You might have a useful critique. I sure as hell could be taking a dumb approach.

The exact problem I have is just how to pad those fields with exactly the right amount of whitespace.

I *did* figure out a solution. Sort of.

But it seems like a hack to me.

I just suspect there is a more efficient, fast, or elegant way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The "hack" part is calling a second print function and using the difference between the character count and the maxlength constant to add whitespace after the data. See lines 27-39 for that. It works… But?

Shouldn't I just be able to pad the array directly?

Can't figure it out!

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** array-ops/5.c
    Template for inputting data from stdin using getchar().
        Sets arraymax to prevent overflow, truncates array if smaller than 
    arraymax, right pads short entries with spaces, and quits gracefully. 
    (Really? You're /sure/ about that last?) */

#define ARRAYMAX 8

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    int count;
    char array[ARRAYMAX];

    ch = getchar();
    count = 0;
    // no overflows, unclosed processes, or extra keystrokes needed
    while(count < ARRAYMAX && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        array[count++] = ch;

        ch = getchar();
    }

    int diff = (ARRAYMAX - count);
    //printf("count: %d\n", count); // check
    //printf("diff: %d\n", diff); // check again. off-by-one?

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%c", array[i]);
    }

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < diff; j++) {
        printf("%s", " ");
    }

    //printf("|\n"); // check, spaces really there?
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

BTW, I really searched for the answer to this before posting. Feel free to knock me over with a feather, but it seemed that everyone was trying to solve a slightly different problem, especially a cavalier indifference to data protection and buffer overflows. So I don't think this is a duplicate question.

[edit] Here is the revised code. It incorporates Joachim's solution and an if-else loop to isolate a truncated string. It's still not the best, but...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** array-ops/5r.c
    Template for inputting data from stdin using getchar().
        Sets arraymax to prevent overflow, truncates array if smaller than 
    arraymax, right pads short entries with spaces, and quits gracefully. */

#define ARRAYMAX 8

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    int count;
    char array[ARRAYMAX];

    ch = getchar();
    count = 0;
    // no overflows, unclosed processes, or extra keystrokes needed
    while(count < ARRAYMAX && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        array[count++] = ch;

        ch = getchar();
    }

    int diff = (ARRAYMAX - count);
    printf("count: %d\n", count); // check
    printf("diff: %d\n", diff); // check again for off-by-one

    if(count == ARRAYMAX) {
        printf("%.*s", ARRAYMAX, array);
    } else {
        printf("%.*s%*c", count, array, diff, ' ');
    }

    printf("|--array ends there\n"); // check, spaces really there?
    //printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why you don't want to use `fgets`.

Comment: @ooga Probably because the OP doesn't want the ending newline inside the array, or have it terminated like a string.

Comment: Instead of writing output byte-by-byte and padding the field using file I/O, you might instead use `memset (array + count, ' ', diff);` to set all remaining bytes in the array to spaces. Follow that by `fwrite (array, sizeof array, 1, FP);`, replacing FP with a file pointer, which may be `stdout` as your code above suggests.

Comment: @ooga. I added a link to Seacord's article. And  Chrono Kitsune, my rep does not allow me to @ you, but, funny, but I was just researching memset today, thinking that approach might be better.

Comment: @RichardG.Crockett I accidentally reversed the order for the second and third parameters of `fwrite` (I always do), but other than that, I'm thinking it will work better. The correct usage should read `fwrite (array, 1, sizeof array, FP);`.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I was just now setting down to mess with that. Good catch. The code I posted was test code using stdout. That's temporary for testing only. Ultimately I'm using the fwrite function. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see e.g. [this `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), you will might notice the `*` format modifier, that can be used to set the field width or precision through an argument.

Can be used such as

```
printf("%.*s%*c\n", count, array, diff, ' ');
```

This will print `count` characters from `array`, then print one space right-justified by `diff` characters, and end it with a newline.

For an input of e.g. `"ab\n"`, it should print `"ab      "` followed by a newline.

Comment: Looking stuff up... Testing... :)

Comment: Yes indeedy! Simple and elegant. Just the thing! I knew it had to be something like that. Time to seriously spend more time with the "fine" manual. Thanks!

Comment: Joachim, I like your solution and I've been tinkering with it. Is there a way **not** to print the padding `' '` at the end if `count=ARRAYMAX`. I've read the link and I've messed with it, but every time I fill `array` with `8` chars, (`count=8`; `diff=0`), I still get an additional `' '` tacked on the end of the ouput pushing the field size to `9`. When `count < ARRAYMAX` it works fine. Any thought/trick?

Comment: OK. I think I got it: printf("%-*s", ARRAYMAX, array);

Comment: Yes, I see what you did. Set the field width of `ARRAYMAX`, beginning at the left, and then printing array. Only issue to watch out for, `ARRAYMAX` is a **minimum** field width (nothing to keep `array` from flowing on past `ARRAYMAX` chars if `array` exceeds `ARRAYMAX`). I know you are controlling that with the `while` loop and that will work fine, just know the `printf` isn't going to prevent printing `array[ARRAYMAX+1000]`. Good bit of learning, thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. Did you see the stuff we did here. Had to tweak the code a bit. Getting an added space when the count is the size of array max. Do you know of a better way? But, anyway, thank you much for the clues needed for a learning journey.

Comment: @RichardG.Crockett, Your `if, else` comes about as close as you can get there. **but...** (and there is always a 'but'), you have strayed off into `undefined behavior` passing a `non-null-terminated` string to `printf` using the `%s` format specifier. (no limit on **length** of string and no `null-terminator`) I think to be safe you would need the `precision specifier` as well `printf("%.*s", ARRAYMAX, array);` to insure the output is limited to `ARRAYMAX` chars.

Comment: Ah. Excellent catch. I have edited the code above to reflect.  The title of this Q did have "Secure!" One thing I'm happy with is by trashing all the iterations and only calling the minimum # of writes, this code should very fast on even large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the easiest way would be to initialize `array` to all `spaces` (hex `0x20`). Then, no matter what the input, your `array` is always `space-padded` to `8-chars`. This works regardless of the length of the input, and without having to worry about the number of characters input, or calculating the length of the pad. Further, it does not rely on characters being input. If the user (you), just hit `[enter]`, you still get your `8-char` padded array.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYMAX 8

int main()
{
    int ch;
    int count = 0;
    char array[ARRAYMAX] = { 0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20 };
    int i = 0;

    while((ch = getchar()) && count < ARRAYMAX && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        array[count++] = ch;

    printf("\n         01234567\n");

    printf(" array: '");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYMAX; i++)
        printf("%c", array[i]);

    printf ("'\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/padstr8
Hi

         01234567
 array: 'Hi      '

$ ./bin/padstr8
It's all Good

         01234567
 array: 'It's all'
```

**Note:** if you are using `gcc`, you can initialize all elements of `array` with:

```
char array[ARRAYMAX] = { [0 ... 7] = 0x20 };
```

or more readable:

```
char array[ARRAYMAX] = { [0 ... 7] = ' ' };
```

That cuts down initializing every element.

---

This exercise started me off on a tangent to see what type of function I could write that would take a `char array`, whether allocated (on `stack` or `heap`), or not at all and simply passed as `NULL` pointer, and an accompanying `field size` that would allow me to fill a fixed field size and make that available in `main()`. I've tinkered a bit, and hit on something that if I don't find any more hidden gotchas, seems like it is doing a decent job. It is passed along for food for thought:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYMAX 8

/** fill 'str' with input from stdin rt-padded to 'szfld'.
*  if 'str' exists and has storage, 'str' is filled with
*  input up to a maximum size of 'szfld' chars. If input
*  is less than 'szfld', 'str' is rt-padded with spaces.
*  if 'str' is 'NULL', 'szfld' chars are allocated.
*  NOTE: 'str' is NOT null-terminated. (intentionally)
*/
char *fillfield (char *str, int szfld)
{
    char ch = 0;
    int  count = 0;
    int  i = 0;

    szfld = (szfld > ARRAYMAX) ? ARRAYMAX : szfld;

    if (str)
        for (i = 0; i < szfld; i++)
            str[i] = 0;
    else
        str = calloc (szfld, sizeof (char));

    printf ("\n Input: ");
    while((ch = getchar()) && count < ARRAYMAX && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        str[count++] = ch;

    if (count >= ARRAYMAX && ch != '\n')
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) ;

    char *p = str + szfld - 1;
    while (!*p && p >= str) *p-- = 0x20;

    return str;    
}

int main() {

    char field_1[6];
    fillfield (field_1, 6);                 /* fill existing array */

    char *field_2 = fillfield (NULL, 6);    /* allocate/fill array */

    printf ("\n field_1: '%.*s'\n", 6, field_1);
    printf (" field_2: '%.*s'\n\n", 6, field_2);

    if (field_2) free (field_2);            /* clean up allocation  */

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/padstrf

 Input: hi

 Input: hi

 field_1: 'hi    '
 field_2: 'hi    '

$ ./bin/padstrf

 Input:  hi

 Input:  hi

 field_1: ' hi   '
 field_2: ' hi   '

$ ./bin/padstrf

 Input: truncate

 Input: truncate

 field_1: 'trunca'
 field_2: 'trunca'

$ ./bin/padstrf

 Input:

 Input:

 field_1: '      '
 field_2: '      '
```

Comment: Thanks David. I like Joachim's approach better. It allows me to move this function to a lib and set my array sizes in a header file rather than have to manually fill each one. There will be a lot of fields!

Comment: No problem. There is more than 1 way to skin this cat. Joachim's answer is great, and I agree it will be easier to move to a function. Passing the `field` size to an input function would also work, but would take a bit more code that his example.

Comment: Cool. Er, did you add in the last shorthand for gcc? I did not see that before. That's pretty nifty.

Comment: Yes, I did, I didn't like that long string of 0x20 (spaces). Hey, with Joachim's solution, I like it, I've been tinkering with it, and I cannot get it to limit the field to `count` when `count=ARRAYMAX` and `diff=0`. If you find the trick in your 'fine' reading, drop a comment. For some reason, When I specify precision with `'.'` in the format string with `%.*s%*c` as suggested, the field size jumps to `ARRAYMAX+1` (with an appended `' '`) when `count=ARRAYMAX`. I'll do the same and drop a comment back if I find the solution.

Comment: Yes. I just discovered that! I was reading the link Joachim used. It is much easier to vgrep than the man page. I ended up putting the printf in an if-else block. It checks for equality between count and arraymax and just prints as usual if so, but again, that seems kludgy. Searching...

Comment: Figured it out. (Pretty sure) See my comment under Joachim's answer. This illustrates that it behooves one to not be too quick about accepting an answer!

Comment: Good, I'm curious. This whole thing started me out on another `tinker tangent` and I ended up trying to work out a function that would do the same thing. I posted mine, you post yours `:)`

Comment: Well, uh, before I posted the new code, I gave it some more tests. It worked on numbers only. I came up with a workaround. That's all. Coming up...